# SQL JOIN Returning 2 Different Fields from a Single Field With Lookup

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, lookup

I have the following table that contains essentially the correct data I need:
TB1:

```
P   PR  C   CR  QTY
--  --  --  --  ---
Z   01  C   02  14
X   02  D   01  1
Q   03  Z   01  22
D   01  S   04  9
```

What I need to do is replace the P+PR and C+CR columns with a single column for each that I fetch from my lookup table:
LUT2:

```
CATNUM  R   RNUM    RREV
------  --  ----    ----
Z-01    01  Z       01
X       02  X       02
Q-03    03  Q       03
D       01  D       01
C-02    02  C       02
S-04    04  S       04
```

The results I am after are the following:

```
PNUM    CNUM    QTY
----    ----    ---
Z-01    C-02    14
X       D       1
Q-03    Z-01    22
D       S-04    9
```

Essentially I lookup and return LUT2.CATNUM for PNUM and LUT2.CATNUM for CNUM based upon lookups on TB1.P=LUT2.RNUM AND TB1.PR=LUT2.RREV and TB1.C=LUT2.RNUM AND TB1.PR=LUT2.RREV

Any ideas how I should approach this? Accuracy takes priority over efficiency here.

Comment: Join LUT2 twice with ON predicates you've specified.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select coalesce(tp.catnum, t1.p) as p,
       coalesce(tc.catnum, t1.c) as c,
       t1.qty
from tb1 left join
     tb2 tp
     on t1.p || '-' || t1.pr = tp.catnum left join
     tb2 tc
     on t1.c || '-' || t1.cr = tc.catnum;
```

You haven't specified the database you are using so this uses the standard operator `||` for string concatenation.

EDIT:

Oh, I see the values are in the other columns:

```
select coalesce(tp.catnum, t1.p) as p,
       coalesce(tc.catnum, t1.c) as c,
       t1.qty
from tb1 left join
     tb2 tp
     on t1.p = tp.rnum and t1.pr = tp.r left join
     tb2 tc
     on t1.c = tc.rnum and t1.cr = tc.r;
```

Comment: In your example should t1 and t2 actually be tb1 and tb2? When I change these this appears to provide the results I am after. Database is MS SQL.

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of coalesce above? The following would appear to be correct for my stated data:  
   select tp.catnum as pnum,
           tc.catnum as cnum,
           tb1.qty
    from tb1 left join
         tb2 tp
         on tb1.p = tp.rnum and tb1.pr = tp.rrev left join
         tb2 tc
         on tb1.c = tc.rnum and tb1.cr = tc.rrev;

Comment: @cixelsyd . . . I wasn't sure if the values would always match in the second table.  The `coalesce()` is for the cases where they don't match.